# How to call the more specific method of struct instead of trait?

Tags: rust

There's an external crate which implement a trait but overrides it as well on the struct too:

```
// external crate

struct Dog;

impl Talker for Dog {
    fn speak(&self, t: &str) {
        println!("dog says: {}", t);
    }
}

impl Dog {
    fn speak(&self) {
        println!("woof");
    }
}
```

Now from my own code, I'm looking to access the `.speak()` method which is directly defined on the structure itself. However since I have `use external::Talker`, the only `speak` method I can call is `speak(&str)`.

I have also tried:

```
(d as &Dog).speak();
                 -- this function takes 1 arguments but 0 arguments were supplied
```

How can I access the more specific method?

Comment: The inherent method should be called in preference to the trait method. Are you sure the inherent method is in scope? You've said this is an external crate and `speak` is not public, so it could just be that...

Answer (score 1):

Postfix method call syntax like `d.speak()` is syntactic sugar for:

```
<Dog as Talker>::speak(&d);
```

or

```
Dog::speak(&d);
```

Depending which is in scope. If both are in scope, the inherent method (ie. the one directly implemented for the `Dog` type) is prefered over the trait implementation.

Comment: I have both the struct and trait in scope, `speak` is also not public on either of them.

Comment: Methods of traits are always public if the trait is public. Inherent methods are private unless explicitly declared as `pub`.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense now!